# A love letter, 13 years after death

Tags: riddle, knowledge

You walk into your room, and give a quick glance at your iPad that you've had for so long. It's been a while (to be exact, 6, no, 13 years) since everything's, well, *happened*, and you've realized that it's probably a good time to apologize to me. Nothing about you is really the same anymore. Getting shot kind of does tend to ruin your chances of succeeding in life. You sigh and run your hand through your hair. Your iPad blinks and it's... wow, it's a letter from *me*. Of all others.

> hey, i just implore you to understand that the occurences of that night really made me do some thinkin. and i just hope you also understand that it really changed me. as soon as i shot you i realized the exact repurcussions of my actions. you, me, the others, we all made it to this afterlife, or... thin that comes after death. it's just like you, really. all bubbles and stuff. they keep on floatin around. i crossed the path of some of the others, but understandably, they all still tried to go as fast as possible. i suppose that's fair punishment for all that i did.
>
> i really miss you. i hope you get that i'm bein sincere and all here. i understand that i had to appreciate the relationship that you and i had and i coulda kept it goin by talkin to you about my feelins for you. i shouldn'ta tried to go against the relationship system, but i had too strong feelins for you for me to stop myself.
>
> i'm sorry for killin you. it's been a long time, and i just hope that you are able to see this and try to stay for a period of time if our paths cross again.
>
> regards,

The signature is blotched out with a single tear.

---

Who am I, and who are you?

In your answer, please explain how you figured out the riddle, and explanations of the hints if you used them.

Hint 1

> There is a reason why you had trouble with how long it's been since you've seen me.

Hint 2

> Certain letters have been intentionally omitted from the letter. The bad grammar is also intentional.

Hint 3

> You're probably staring the answer in the face right now.

---

I'm open to feedback, as this is my first post here on P.SE. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it to do with phones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're...

> Eridan Ampora from Homestuck. He types like that and...

(Spoilers follow)

> He killed his girlfriend and they met up in the dreambubble afterlife.

The 6/13 is a reference to

> his species' time; six sweeps is equivalent to 13 years.

Comment: I like this answer. I wonder if the missing letters (qv) are a reference to quod vide or if this connection is spurious.

Comment: Correct! You really were staring the answer in the face if you looked at my profile pic.

Comment: @Anathema: Probably just spurious.

Comment: @Eridan: Not quite sure if a webcomic reference should be a puzzle for P.SE. Don't get me wrong, I'm a *huge* Homestuck fan, but this sort of straddles the border between puzzles and pure trivia.